# Infinitives of verb

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

State how the infinitive is used in the following sentence:-
"It is delightful *to hear* the sound of the sea"

The answer hints that the infinitive is in apposition to 'it'
How does this explain anything?
Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence:

> It is delightful to hear the sound of the sea.

The word **it** in that sentence is a dummy pronoun, not an appositive.

Note that the same sentence can be rephrased as

> To hear the sound of the sea is delightful.

The words *to hear the sound of the sea* are a subordinate infinitive clause that is the subject of the main clause. Its verb is *to hear*, with the direct object *the sound of the sea*.

Then, in the process called **extraposition**, that infinitive clause is moved to the end of the main clause, and the dummy pronoun **it** is added to serve as the syntactic subject.

Note that it is not an appositive, because it is not grammatical to say
**It** to hear the sound of the sea is delightful.

References to *it-extraposition* :

[Google Books "Students Intro to English Grammar"](https://books.google.com/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA247&dq=%22At%20least%20two%20distinctive%20properties%20of%20the%20subject%20outlined%20in%20%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYqNGDpe_sAhWLWc0KHVYcAuQQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22At%20least%20two%20distinctive%20properties%20of%20the%20subject%20outlined%20in%20%22&f=false)
Chapter 15, 3.1 "Extraposition"

[Wikipedia "Extraposition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition)
It-extraposition